# Implement a keyboard like the sms app's one?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Someone knows how to get a keyboard similiar to that  you can find in the sms app on the iphone, means a keybord with a kind of textField over it that stretch when you type long text.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `UIToolbar` above the keyboard - [this is a good start](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/02/iphone-keyboard-toolbar/).

Comment: Ok thank you, i read it and it gives me a good start, but i still don't know what kind of textFields i should embed in it to have this kind of stretchable field.

Comment: See UISearchBar - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html